# Using Javascript Redirect On Landing Page For Facebook Ad With Google Analytics

Tags: facebook, redirect, google-analytics

I am running a Javascript redirect (with location.replace) to redirect someone who clicks on a Facebook ad to the desired page I want them to visit. The reason I did that was so I could track the visitor's activity. I added Google Analytics before the location.replace and then uploaded it.

It seems that the only time it tracks any activity is when I test the page (type the exact URL in and visit it). I know for a fact, after checking my Facebook ads insights, that 40 people have clicked on the link, yet Google Analytics tracks none of it.

Why would Google Analytics not pick up the activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google analytics does not have time to send the tracker before the page is redirected.

Try adding a `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(location.replace('http://www.YOUR-LINK.com/'), 100);
```

Comment: Is that enough time to send the tracker?

Comment: @MxmastaMills If it not sending, you can increase the time from `100` to `200`. I wasn't sure exactly how you had the page set up and how users where interacting so I went for the least amount of time. It appeared to be a bounce page but not sure.

Comment: Yeah it was literally just a bounce page. I just have no idea how long it takes Google Analytics to send the tracker. I obviously want the load time to be quick for the user so they aren't waiting for the destination page to load but I want to make sure it's a long enough delay to send the tracker. With the setTimeout in there at 100 it acts pretty much the same but I'm assuming there's a quick delay that's difficult to pick up on as a human :p